An application of Riemann Mapping theorem to find a map with derivative strictly bigger than 1
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{D} = \{|z| < 1\}$ be a proper, simply connected open subset. Show that there exists a holomorphic map $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a) > 1$ for some $a\in \Omega$.
My attempt: From Riemann Mapping Theorem we know that there is a map $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{D}$ such that $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a) > 0$. Then there is also an inverse map $g(z) = f^{-1}(z)$ such that $g(0) = a$ and $g'(z) = \frac{1}{f'(g(z))}$. Then we have a composite map $F = \psi_a \circ g(z)$
$$\mathbb{D} \overset{g}{\longmapsto} \Omega \overset{i}{\longmapsto} \mathbb{D} \overset{\psi_a}{\longmapsto} \mathbb{D}$$
Where $i$ is the inclusion map and $\psi_a = \frac{a-z}{1-\overline{a}z}$ for some $a \in \mathbb{D}$ non zero.
$$F(0) = \psi_a (g(0)) = \psi_a(a) = 0$$
So by Schwarz Lemma $|F'(0)| \leq 1$.
$$F'(z) = \psi_a'(g(z)) g'(z) = \frac{-1(1-\overline{a}z)-(-\overline{a})(a-z)}{(1-\overline{a}z)^2}g'(z) = \frac{-1+|a|^2}{(1-\overline{a}z)^2}g'(z)$$
$$|F'(0)| = \left|\frac{-1+|a|^2}{(1-\overline{a}a)^2}g'(0) \right| =\left| \frac{- (1-|a|^2)}{(1-|a|^2)^2} \frac{1}{f'(a)}\right| = \frac{1}{(1-|a|^2)|f'(a)|} \leq 1$$
So
$$|f'(a)| \geq \frac{1}{1-|a|^2} > 1 \quad \text{since $a \neq 0$ and $a \in \mathbb{D}$}$$
I wonder if this is correct and look for any suggestions on how to extend this to the case when $a = 0$. In particular I want to find a map $h$ from a triangle inside unit disc to unit disc with $ h(0) = 0 $ and $h'(0) >1 $

when $a=0$ can't you argue that $\vert g'(0)\vert \leq 1$ by Schwarz and that the inequality must be strict since $\Omega \neq \mathbb D$

Could you clarify how $\Omega \neq \mathbb{D}$ implies that inequality must be strict. I do not see it.

Schwarz equality conditions tell you $\big \vert g'(0)\big \vert =1\implies g(z) = \lambda \cdot z$ for some $\vert \lambda\vert = 1$ [you can of course use Parseval if you don't like Schwarz for some reason]. This implies $G:\mathbb D \longrightarrow \Omega $ given by $G(z) = z = g\big(\lambda^{-1} \cdot z\big)$ which implies $\mathbb D\subseteq \Omega$ and we know $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb D$

Thank you very much!

$f\circ g =\text{id}_{\mathbb D}$ and $g(z) = a + \sum_{k=1}^\infty c_k z^k$.  For $r\in \big(0,1\big)$, application of Parseval gives
$\vert a\vert^2 + \vert c_1\vert^2 r^{2} \leq \vert a\vert^2 +\sum_{k=1}^\infty \vert c_k\vert^2 r^{2k}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\big \vert g\big(r\cdot e^{i\theta}\big)\big\vert^2d\theta\leq 1\implies \vert g'(0)\vert = \vert c_1\vert\leq 1 $
noting $\vert c_1\vert =1 \implies g(z) = c_1 z\implies g\big(\mathbb D\big) = \mathbb D \subseteq \Omega\subset \mathbb D$ [impossible]
Conclude $\vert f'(a)\vert = \left\vert \frac{1}{g'(0)}\right\vert \gt 1$
